# Why i can not use getimagesize PHP with this image?

Tags: php, getimagesize

Why i can not use getimagesize PHP with this image ?

For this image i can get getimagesize  PHP, work good.

```
<?PHP
        $source = "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/da/7a/19/da7a19a0c3daabe579ecca21d1ae32c3--felt-wool-felting-projects.jpg";
        $dimension = getimagesize($source);
        $width = $dimension[0];
        $height = $dimension[1];

        echo $width;
        echo "<BR>";
        echo $height;
?>
```

But for this image Why i can not get getimagesize PHP ?

```
<?PHP
        $source = "https://shorebread.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/kitty-cat-reaching_138482216-2000x500.jpg";
        $dimension = getimagesize($source);
        $width = $dimension[0];
        $height = $dimension[1];

        echo $width;
        echo "<BR>";
        echo $height;
?>
```

How can i do for use getimagesize PHP on every image ?

Comment: Because: user agent blocking?? How did you debug the second resource to be available for remote access?

Comment: This one worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680906/1403118

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the website doesn't allow "[hot-linking](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking)" or that it blocks PHP's user agent.

If you try getting the data from the URL you will get a ***HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden*** response:

```
php > $dimension = getimagesize($source);
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(https://shorebread.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/kitty-cat-reaching_138482216-2000x500.jpg):        
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

 in php shell code on line 1
```

If you download the image first, and do the same from disk it works:

```
php > $dimension = getimagesize("kitty-cat-reaching_138482216-2000x500.jpg");
php > print_r($dimension);
Array
(
    [0] => 2000
    [1] => 500
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="2000" height="500"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

So it is not that `getimagesize` doesn't work on all images. It couldn't download the image itself.

Comment: how to download image from site that blocks PHP's user agent ?

Comment: You can use `ini_set` before making any requests. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974742/change-user-agent-using-php).